# how to handle WebSocket.send error

Tags: javascript, websocket

I'm writing a web application - consider it's a chat based on WebSocket. I need to be sure all the messages entered by the user would be delivered in correct order. I should not lose any message. I should not deliver any message twice.

When the socket closes I got socket.onclose() callback. However socket.send() could be called when the socket was closed but onclose() callback hasn't been called yet. socket.send() doesn't return anything, it even doesn't raise onerror() callback. How can I be sure that socket.send() sent the message properly?

This is the code I've written. sendMessage() pushes the message to the queue and flush() method shifts all the messages and sends them. Is the code safe?

```
        queue: [],
        flush: function() {
            for (;;) {
                if (this.queue.length == 0) break;
                if (this.socket.readyState != 1) break; // *1*
                this.socket.send(this.queue[0]);        // *2*
                if (this.socket.readyState != 1) break; // *3*
                this.queue.shift();
            }
        },
        sendMessage: function(msg) {
            this.queue.push(msg);
            this.flush();
        }
```